# Directory API moving an organization unit using google api for java to another organization unit

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am testing moving an organization unit from under one parent to another.  Right now i have a following OUs:

```
YourDomain.com
-Middle Schools
--Grade07
-Elementary Schools
--Grade01
--Garde02
```

I want to move Grade 07 to Elementary School OU for example.  Here is my code snippet:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Middle Schools");
    list.add("Grade 07");
    OrgUnit ou = sDirectory.orgunits().get("my_customer", list).execute();
    ou.setParentOrgUnitPath("/Elementary Schools");
    ou.setOrgUnitPath("/Elementary Schools/Grade 07");
    list.clear();
    list.add("Elementary Schools");
    list.add("Grade 07");
    sDirectory.orgunits().update("my_customer", list, ou).execute();
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Org unit not found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Org unit not found"
}
```

What did i miss?

Comment: Anyone can help answer this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.  I realize you only need to update the parentOrgUnitPath.  So the above code looks ike this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Middle Schools");
    list.add("Grade 07");
    OrgUnit ou = sDirectory.orgunits().get("my_customer", list).execute();
    ou.setParentOrgUnitPath("/Elementary Schools");
    sDirectory.orgunits().update("my_customer", list, ou).execute();
```