# Trying to move Organization Unit under another OrgUnit fails

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I have the following Org Units hierarchy:

```
..
../Unit1
..../SubUnit
../Unit2
```

I'm trying to move SubUnit from Unit1 to Unit2 with code like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Unit1");
list.add("SubUnit");
OrgUnit orgUnit = directoryService.orgunits().get("my_customer", list).execute();
orgUnit.setParentOrgUnitPath("/Unit2");

directoryService.orgunits().update("my_customer", list, orgUnit ).execute();
```

but it always fails with:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Parent Org unit not found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Parent Org unit not found"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

The error message is quite clear, but the ParentOrgUnit exists at the moment of the call and its path is provided correctly. I tried many times with different units with same result using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
    <version>directory_v1-rev53-1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help?

The only question I've found about but it doesn't help:
[Directory API moving an organization unit using google api for java to another organization unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000653/directory-api-moving-an-organization-unit-using-google-api-for-java-to-another-o#)

Comment: Try orgUnit.setParentOrgUnitPath("Unit2"); I tried with above code, even I got the same error. So, changed this line by removing the root and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't work for me. I'm getting the same error with or without root withing ParentOrgUnitPath.